# TypeORM Select Specific Column Only

Tags: sql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM. Via **Repository/Entity pattern** and `findOneOrFail`, **I want to select a specific column (isBusiness) only for my results.**

```
this.userProfile.findOneOrFail({
            join: {
                innerJoin: {
                    user: "usr.user",
                    preference: "usr.preference"
                },
                alias: "usr"
            },
            where: {
                user: {
                    userId: userId
                }
            },
            select: ['id', 'preference'],
            relations: ['preference']
```

This will return:

1. Id of an user profile.
2. The preference row related to the user profile.

The example JSON payload:

```
  {
    id: 99,
    preference: { 
        id : 912,
        theme: 'dark'
        isBusiness: true
        }
}
```

I need to select only the `isBusiness` column so that I would have

```
{
    id: 99,
    preference: { 
        isBusiness: true
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't use `preference.isBusiness` only to the select object as it only accepts a keyof the `userProfile` schema like this:

```
select: ['id', 'preference.isBusiness'],
```

Thank you for your help as I couldn't find any solution for the repository/entity way. For the query builder approach, it's all good as there's a bunch of documentation/references for it.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeORM 0.3 we can use a new way to select columns in repositories.

```
select: {
        id: true,
        enroll_id: true,
        person: {
          id: true,
          name: true,
          birth: true,
        },
        course: { name: true },
        grade: { name: true },
        classGroup: { name: true },
      },
```

Comment: How do we provide an alias here?